# After stop GULP with CMD+Z got an error: ✗ ... Uhoh. Got error %s ... listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: gulp, ionic-framework

I was working as usual until I stop the server by mistake by playing `CMD+Z` and got this very big error on my terminal:

```
[18:02:27] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Projects/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/gulpfile.js
[18:02:27] Starting 'sass'...
[18:02:27] Starting 'lint'...
[18:02:29] Finished 'lint' after 1.28 s
[18:02:29] Starting 'run-ionic'...
Running dev server: http://192.168.1.4:8100
 ✗
 ✗ ... Uhoh. Got error %s ... listen EADDRINUSE
 ✗ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
    at Server.listen (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tiny-lr-fork/lib/server.js:138:15)
    at Object.IonicTask.start (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:164:16)
    at /home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:40:10
    at Object.IonicTask.getAddress (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:640:11)
    at Object.IonicTask.loadSettings (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:71:8)
    at Object.IonicTask.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:33:8)
    at Object.Ionic.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic.js:537:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:10:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
[18:02:30] 'run-ionic' errored after 1.43 s
[18:02:30] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command failed:  ✗
 ✗ ... Uhoh. Got error %s ... listen EADDRINUSE
 ✗ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
    at Server.listen (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tiny-lr-fork/lib/server.js:138:15)
    at Object.IonicTask.start (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:164:16)
    at /home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:40:10
    at Object.IonicTask.getAddress (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:640:11)
    at Object.IonicTask.loadSettings (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:71:8)
    at Object.IonicTask.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:33:8)
    at Object.Ionic.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic.js:537:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:10:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3

Details:
    killed: false
    code: 1
    signal: null
    stdout: Running dev server: http://192.168.1.4:8100

    stderr:  ✗
 ✗ ... Uhoh. Got error %s ... listen EADDRINUSE
 ✗ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
    at Server.listen (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tiny-lr-fork/lib/server.js:138:15)
    at Object.IonicTask.start (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:164:16)
    at /home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:40:10
    at Object.IonicTask.getAddress (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:640:11)
    at Object.IonicTask.loadSettings (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:71:8)
    at Object.IonicTask.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:33:8)
    at Object.Ionic.run (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic.js:537:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mretana/.nvm/v0.10.34/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:10:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

The examples in the docs did not tell me anything, do you have a clue?

I already nvm use 0.10.X and nothing, restart computer and nothing. Also I checked my code and everything is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just restart your console, I just went thru all of this already